# I need to have a flash overlay disappear after it runs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, myspace

I'm doing a myspace profile for a client,

I'd like to run a flash animation as an overlay and then once it runs, have it completely disappear, set to display: none or any other fashion of that.

It must be myspace friendly (no javascript).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this cannot be done without JavaScript. The only way I can see it be done is by using ExternalInterface from the flash to call a JavaScript function in the HTML page to set it to display:none.

The flash cannot set itself to display:none. Maybe if you set the wmode parameter to transparent and leave the last frame empty it can behave as you want. But I can't try that here on my phone

Comment: Ended up using a gif instead of a flash intro and since it was transparent it took care of the issue itself!! 

Thanks, for the help.

Matt